# Differentiability of composite functions

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I am supposed to prove that if a certain complex ($U\to\mathbb{C}$ with $U\subset\mathbb{C}$) function $f$ is continuous at $z_0\in U$, a certain complex ($f(U)\to\mathbb{C}$) function $g$ is differentiable with $g'(f(z_0))\ne0$, and $g\circ f$ is differentiable at $z_0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $z_0$. My question is whether $g\circ f$ *can* be differentiable if $f$ is not? All my lecture notes and textbook say is that $g\circ f$ is differentiable if both $g$ and $f$ are differentiable, but not that this is a necessary condition, so I'm a bit lost with this question.

Comment: How about $g$ : a constant function

Comment: The contrapositive of the original statement basically gives you love_sodam's comment

Comment: But if $g$ was a constant function we would have $g'(f(z_0))=0$, though it is explicitly said in the question that this is not the case. So is the answer that $f$ must be differentiable *because* $g$ cannot be a constant function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Logic

The theorem is: If $\color{red}{f\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{ is continuous at }}z_0}$ and $\color{blue}{g'(f(z_0))\ne0}$ and $\color{purple}{g\circ f\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{ is differentiable at }}z_0}$ then $\color{orange}{f\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{ is differentiable at }}z_0}$.

The [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) is: If
$\color{orange}{f\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{ is }}\style{font-family:inherit;}{\textbf{not}}\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{ differentiable at }}z_0}$ then $\color{red}{f\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{ is }}\style{font-family:inherit;}{\textbf{not}}\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{ continuous at }}z_0}$ or $\color{blue}{g'(f(z_0))=0}$ or $\color{purple}{g\circ f\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{ is }}\style{font-family:inherit;}{\textbf{not}}\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{ differentiable at }}z_0}$.

If we force "$\color{purple}{g\circ f\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{ is differentiable at }}z_0}$", then either $\color{red}{f\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{ is }}\style{font-family:inherit;}{\textbf{not}}\style{font-family:inherit;}{\text{ continuous at }}z_0}$ or $\color{blue}{g'(f(z_0))=0}$.

An easy way to make that or statement happen is if $g$ is a constant function so that $g'(f(z_0))=0$. But what about other choices of $g$?

## Answer

Yes, $g\circ f$ can be differentiable at a point even if $f$ is not. For instance, suppose $g(z)=z^2$ so that $g'(0)=2*0=0$. And suppose that $f(a+bi)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if }a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\\
a+bi & \text{ if }a,b\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$. Then $g\circ f$ is differentiable at $0$ even though $f$ is not differentiable anywhere.

Comment: In both your example and love_sodam's, we have $g'(f(z_0))=0$, though it is said this cannot be the case. My interpretation of this is that I should prove that if $f$ is not differentiable at $z_0$, but $g\circ f$ is, then $g'(f(z_0))=0$. I am unsure this is correct though.

Comment: @GuilhermeFerrão, The contrapositive is the key to the first question. How about this: The original statement which had $g'\ne0$ in it had the conclusion that $f$ is differentiable. So flipping that around we get that $g'=0$ is *possible* if $f$ is not differentiable. However, I have not answered your question in the comment of whether $g'=0$ is *required*. I don't know off the top of my head if we could get away with just "$f$ is discontinuous" *without* having $g'=0$. If you care about that, try to modify my example; try to prove it impossible; and then post a new question if you're stuck.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this :)